# Installing prepr package: GNU MP not found in R although gmp is installed

Tags: macos, rstudio, gnu

I am trying to install a package prepr from this tutorial https://prioritizr.github.io/aoh/
I have tried a few different ways but R keeps saying "configure: error: GNU MP not found!". The code is
if (!require(remotes)) install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("dickoa/prepr")

Here are some commands I have tried to install gmp (I'm not sure what else GNU MP could refer too):

- brew install gmp
- sudo install gmp via MacPorts
- Updating RStudio
  None of these approaches have worked for me. What should I do?